# Ruby on rails form submit to js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this code on Ruby on Rails:

```
 simple_form_for :projectssss, :html => {:id => 'projectsssss_opt'} do |f|            
  f.input :name, :label => ("name")                                  
  f.input :title, :label => ('title')                                      
  f.submit "Submit", :id => 'btn'
```

And this Javascript:

```
$.ajax({                                                                     
  type: "POST",                                                            
  url: api_url,                                                            
  data: [ what to put here ???],                                                               
  success: function ( status ) {                            
 alert("HAHA");                                                                                                       }});
```

How can I grab data from a simple form in JS on Ruby on Rails?

Comment: obviously you have to add the data you want to pass to the rails controller.. like name and title in this excample I guess..

Comment: Answering even tough you have low user rating. Don't make me regret it ; ) Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

The data attribute in a ajax post is where you params go.

lets say you have a project id in a data-project value like this

```
<input class="form-input" id="" data-project="<%=@project.id.to_s %>">
```

Then you could do this

```
$(".form-input").focusout(function(){

    var project     = $(this).attr("data-project")
    var params      = {project_id: project}

    $.ajax({
        url: "/some_url/",  
        type: "POST",
            data: params,
            chache:false,
            dateType: "JSON"
         });    
});
```

In you case when you have a form that is submitted I would do this. Add this to the top of you application.js file

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})
```

Add this function

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() { 
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};
```

And when the dom is ready, call the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#projectsssss_opt').submitWithAjax()
})
```